# Pivot table group by year

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I need to create a new calculated column on my pivot table: year.

I know it's possible to put the date into the lines field and manually group from there and it will show up, however my data is too big and I get a run-time error, so I would like to try creating this column using the option of “Calculated Field” but how can I get a year if it only allows me to do simple math (such as multiplication).

[image]

PS. my excel is in Portuguese as the image shows, but what I need is for a new field YEAR to show up.

EDIT:
So my endgame looks something like this, I need to create the column Years, I can't do the way I'm used to because of how many lines there are.

[image]

Comment: You can do more than simple math in calculated field. What formula would you like to apply to your data "Rotulos de Lihna"?

Comment: The formula would be the =YEAR(cell)

Comment: Just write that in the `calculated field` menu and doubleclick the datefield. It should look like `=YEAR(DATE)`

Comment: How are you creating your pivot table?

If by power pivot, you can create some calculated columns representing a hierarchy, and then group them together as an expandable set of columns

Comment: Never heard of power pivot, however my company probably won't allow it

Comment: Using the calculated field won't work for a Year function, because calculated fields can only be placed into the Values section of the Field List

Comment: @Gabriel_Koch when you drag the date column you want to use, it doesn't recognize the data as Date and naturally group it into the date hierarchy (Year, Quarter, Month, Day)?

Comment: @MarkS. it does, but the computer runs out of memory, I got a workaround by creating columns of years and months on the data itself.

Comment: @Gabriel_Koch and does that not work? I'm unsure what the issue is